Sometimes keyboard not working after shutdown with Power Off button

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Laptop: Asus X456UQK, dead battery.

Restarting multiple times won't fix it.

Restart manually with Power Off button instead of Restart button fixed it.
This has happened twice now and this solution worked on both occasions.

I faced this situation it related to Drivers and configuration, You should re-install drivers, try not to hard shutdown
